# htaccess как найти на самописе?

Tags: .htaccess

Появилась задача на новом проекте отредачить htaccess. У заказчика свой сервер, сайт самопис. Захожу я туда значит, через FTP - вообще непонятная структура, сотни папок и ничего непонятно. В классическом случае этот файл лежит в корне, а здесь не могу найти. Подскажите как можно его найти и понять, если ли он там вообще?

Comment: Сайт точно на Apache поднят?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имеется ли доступ к shell?

Способы найти рекурсивно файл.

1. С использованием shell введите в командной строке:
   **find . -name 'htaccess*' -type f**
   и найдите ваш файл.
2. С помощью php обойдите рекурсивно каталоги и найдите файл.
3. Может быть у вас не отображаются скрытые файлы просто?

Comment: Очень запутанная структура была, в которой шарил только программист. Не понимаю зачем такое делать, но, зато подсказал где он лежит. И на этом спасибо)